# Updating Shield UI Chart with values from textboxes on the page

Tags: shieldui

I am using a Shield UI Chart on a page where users can enter 3 values which are than showed on the chart. I have a button which triggers the event. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css"  href="http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/chart/css/shield-chart.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/chart/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/chart/js/shield-chart.all.min.js"></script> 
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var containter = $("#chart").swidget();
    var info = new Array();
    info[0]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
    info[1]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
    info[2]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);
    containter.destroy();
    $("#chart").shieldChart(
        {
            seriesSettings: {
                line: {
                    applyAnimation: {
                        duration: 0
                    },
                    pointMark: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltipSettings: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exportOptions:
            {
                image: false,
                print: false
            },

            axisX: {
                min: 0,
                max: 5
            },

            primaryHeader: {
                text: "Chart"
            },
            dataSeries: [
                {
                    seriesType: 'bar',
                    collectionAlias: 'chart',
                    data: [info[0],info[1],info[2]]
                }
            ]
        }
        );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Refresh Chart</button>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="chart" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: auto;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<p id="demo"></p>

<input type=text id="a" value='123'>Value A</input>
<input type=text id="b" value='23'>Value B</input>
<input type=text id="c" value='3'>Value C</input>
</body>
</html>
```

However there is some error that prevents the values from being displayed. Actually the whole chart won’t show. Where might be my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is one error that you are making which can be resolved in 2 ways:
1. You can remove the

```
 containter.destroy();
```

statement. So You will not recreate the existing chart, but create a new one each time the button is pressed.

1. You could keep the above mentioned statement, but you need to place this code

   $(document).ready(function () {
           var info = new Array();
           info[0]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
           info[1]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("b").value);
           info[2]=parseFloat(document.getElementById("c").value);

   ```
       $("#chart").shieldChart({
           exportOptions:
                 {
                     image: false,
                     print: false
                 },
           tooltipSettings: {
               enabled: false
           },
           seriesSettings: {
               line: {
                   applyAnimation: {
                       duration: 0
                   },
                   pointMark: {
                       enabled: false
                   }
               }
           },
           axisX: {
               min: 0,
               max: 5
           },

           primaryHeader: {
               text: "Chart"
           },

           dataSeries: [
               {
                   seriesType: 'bar',
                   collectionAlias: 'Chart',
                   data: [info[0],info[1],info[2]]
               }
           ]
       });

   });
   ```

so you will already have one chart which to destroy and recreate and you will be able to show the data from the first time page is loaded.